# Android webview: wait with drawing of page until it's completely loaded

Tags: android, webview, reload

I'm working on an android app (just a ChromeWebView that connects to a specific website), and it all works fine, except for the fact that you see the page loading just like on your computer.

Is it possible to, if I click a link for example, wait with the redrawing of the page until it's completely loaded and then pops up at once?

Answer (score 0):

First make your **layout background color white** then make the **WebView invisible**.

after this use **AsyncTask** then put your webview **loading in doInBackground** and when it's finished in **onPostExecute** make your **webview visible**.

so the user will see the white layout first then the visible webview after fully loaded in postexcute

you could use onpagefinished instead of AsyncTask like this :

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { 
// your code } 
});
```

sorry if my english not good